# How do I know If a bank is legit or not

Tags: bank-account, scams

How do I know if an online bank website is legit or not? Is there Syntax Metropolis bank?

Answer (score 8):

The only mention of them I find in a websearch is their own site. A whois lookup (https://www.whois.com/whois/syntaxmbonline.com) says that domain was registered last month via gandi.net, and whoever owns it only paid for one year of registration (extremely unlikely if they plan to be on business longer than that; I've got a 7-year lease on two versions of domain I'm barely using except as a mail address).

This does not square well with their claim to have existed for 15 years.

Their domain registration claims its owner is based in the Netherlands, for whatever that's worth.

And the name sounds inherently bogus to me. Why syntax? Which metropolis? That's an aggressively meaningless identity.

I would assume scam until proven otherwise. In fact, I would assume any bank that I haven't heard of and can't physically visit is a scam until proven otherwise.

FOLLOWUP: I contacted the registrar and pointed out these issues. They agreed and have cancelled the domain. It *is* worth contacting abuse desks and trying to get these crooks shut down.

Comment: +1 for the followup, I didn't know it's actually possible :-D

Comment: The Authoriteit Financiele Markten (AFM, financial watchdog) keeps a record of all companies doing anything financial in the Netherlands (and EU). They provide warnings if a company is apparently fraudulent. They've never heard of this company.

Comment: Which can only happen if the company does zero business in our country, has very recently started (probably not legally trading yet then) or doesn't exist. For example, there are multiple records on [Friesland Bank](https://www.afm.nl/en/professionals/registers/meldingenregisters/goedgekeurde-prospectussen/details?id=1), [Ahold](https://www.afm.nl/en/professionals/registers/meldingenregisters/goedgekeurde-prospectussen/details?id=102) and [ING](https://www.afm.nl/en/professionals/registers/meldingenregisters/goedgekeurde-prospectussen/details?id=1399).

Comment: I could also have pointed out some sloppy formatting in their website, plus not providing the kind of info most banks put on their websites, but I actually have seen banks with no clue about how to communicate effectively. I had to check with my alma mater to make sure that the dot-matrix-printed letter telling me someone had bought my student loan was legitimate.

Comment: Great to know about the registrar - I had no idea they'd be responsive to that

Comment: Not all are; some cater to abusers. And you need to provide evidence to justify their taking action. But the respectable registrar's don't want their names associated with scams and will often take action. Does no harm to ask, if you're willing to invest the time.